# How to calculate $\sum_{i=2}^n {\frac 1{\log_2 i}}$

Tags: calculus

How to calculate 
$$\sum_{i=2}^n {\frac 1{\log_2 i}}$$

Comment: Do you know how to calculate $\sum_{i=2}^n 5$?

Comment: You have every term in the sum being the same ($1/\log_2 n$). Is this what you want? If so, the answer is trivial. If you want the term to be $1/\log_2 i$, it is more difficult.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you meant $$\sum_{i=2}^n \dfrac1{\log_2(i)},$$ then there is no closed form; though you can compute its asymptotic using Euler-Maclaurin formula:
$$\sum_{k=2}^{n} \dfrac1{\log_2(k)} \sim \log 2\times\int_2^n \dfrac{dx}{\log(x)} \sim \dfrac{n}{\log_2(n)}$$

However, if you meant $$\sum_{i=2}^n \dfrac1{\log_2(n)}$$ note that the term inside the summation is independent of $i$ and hence equals (exactly) $$\dfrac{n-1}{\log_2(n)}$$

Comment: $n-1$ on the numerator of the last line

Comment: @ErickWong Thanks. Updated.

Comment: @Jiajun You may be interested in the [logarithmic integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function).

Comment: @user17762 It's helpful! I used it to calculate the complexity of a recursion tree.